# Is there a PSD or PDF available of the homeAsUpIndicator icon drawable?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable

I've currently implemented a style via the http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ website. I used the light version of the style here and I need to change the homeAsUpIndicator icon to white. I've been looking for a while now and haven't been able to find a psd or something of the sort to be able to change the icon to the desired colour (which is white). I've already found the Holo.Dark icon, but that one is transparent and too big when I put it in the ActionBar. Overlaying a colour, is not as good looking as having the original and being able to modify it.

Does anyone know if there is a PSD/PDF with this image? Or an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "up caret" icon and much more in design files available (for free ;) ) [there](http://androiduiux.com/2014/01/10/android-ui-design-kit-for-photoshop-4-4-free-download/)

Comment: Thx, it contains the up caret (it's even white!!).